# How to make Ansible overwrite existing files during remote software installation?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to clone a repository to a remote host and install the software there:

```
---
- hosts: ubuntu-16.04
  become: yes

  tasks:
     - name: Install aptitude
       apt:   
         name: aptitude
         state: latest
         update_cache: yes

     - name: Update apt cache and upgrade packages
       apt:
         update_cache: yes
         upgrade: full
         autoclean: yes
         autoremove: yes

     - name: Clone <name of repository> repository
       git:
         repo: <link to repository>
         dest: /home/test/Downloads/<new directory>
         clone: yes

     - name: Install <name of repository>
       command: chdir=/home/test/Downloads/<new directory> {{ item }}
       with_items:
         - make
         - make install
       become_user: root
       become_method: sudo

     - name: Remove <name of repository> directory
       file:
         path: /home/test/Downloads/<new directory>
         state: absent
```

This works fine if the software isn't already installed on the system. However, if it is and I run the playbook again, then it gets stuck at the "Install ..." task, saying that it failed to create symlinks as files already exist.

The first problem is that several tasks after this one (not shown here) are not executed due to the play exiting there. I could solve this by simply reordering my tasks, but what I really would like to know, please:

- How do I make Ansible overwrite existing files?
- Would you even solve this that way, or would you say that this behavior is fine as the software is already installed? But what if the repository contains newer code the second time it is cloned?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an Ansible question.  The install process is driven by the `Makefile` in your project, and Ansible has no control over how that operates. The solution would be to fix the `Makefile`.

Comment: If altering the Makefile is not an option, the best way to go about this probably is to make Ansible check if the software is already installed?! And then either do nothing, or uninstall it before a new install ... I need to figure out how to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is related to Ansible, rather to the Makefile. Nevertheless, you could simply skip the installation step when the software is already installed.

First you could check if the binary already exists, and based on the output you can skip the installation:

```
name: Check if software exists
stat:
  path: <path to binary>
register: stat_result

name: Install <name of repository>
  command: chdir=/home/test/Downloads/<new directory> {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - make
    - make install
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: The problem may not be caused by Ansible, but I have to implement a solution in may Ansible playbook. The task that checks for the software, as suggested in you example, does complete successfully, but despite the software already being present on the system, the install task is still executed, too, and fails. Is there a way to print the value in stat_result for debugging purposes?

Comment: The repository does not really install a binary but several library files. I just found out that your solution seems to work if I specify the exact name of one of the library files. Before, I specified just the first part and appended a *. This didn't work. I'm going to alter my playbook such that existing software is uninstalled and new software always is installed instead of skipping the installation step. Thanks for your help!